# modpost: "__tracepoint_sched_switch" was exported without definition

Tags: linux-kernel, tracepoint

I am trying to build a kernel module(.ko) to trace context switch of system. So I use the sched_switch tracepoint and want to register my function to it. But When I build my code, there are some errors.

```
ERROR: modpost: "__tracepoint_sched_switch" undefined
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1978: modpost] Error 2
```

Then I added the `MODULE_LICENSE(GPL)` in main.c and `EXPORT_TRACEPOINT_SYMBOL_GPL(sched_switch)` in 'sched.h', but it doesn't work.

```
ERROR: modpost: "__tracepoint_sched_switch" was exported without definition
ERROR: modpost: "__traceiter_sched_switch" was exported without definition
ERROR: modpost: "__SCK__tp_func_sched_switch" was exported without definition
```

I use the register function in this part

```
static int start_sched_tracing(void){
    int ret;
    ret = register_trace_sched_switch(LTRACE_SWITCH_PROBE, NULL);
    if (ret == -1){
        printk("register_trace_sched_switch failed\n");
    }
    ret = register_trace_sched_process_exit(LTRACE_EXIT_PROBE, NULL);
    if (ret == -1){
        printk("register_trace_sched_process_exit failed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Makefile

```
arch := x86
MODULE:= linuxtrace
obj-m += linuxtrace.o

CURRENT_PATH:=$(shell pwd)
LINUX_KERNEL:=$(shell uname -r)
LINUX_KERNEL_PATH:=/usr/src/linux-headers-$(LINUX_KERNEL)

CPPFLAGS += -I$(LINUX_KERNEL_PATH)/include \
            -I$(LINUX_KERNEL_PATH)/arch/x86/include \
            -I$(LINUX_KERNEL_PATH)/arch/x86/include/generated \

            
all:
    make -C $(LINUX_KERNEL_PATH) M=$(CURRENT_PATH) modules
clean:
    make -C $(LINUX_KERNEL_PATH) M=$(CURRENT_PATH) clean
```

Comment: `was exported without definition` means that you attemp to export symbol from the source, which doesn't **define** that symbol. It is incorrect to call `EXPORT_TRACEPOINT_SYMBOL_GPL` macro (and other EXPORT macros) from the header file, this macro should be called from the **source** file, which defines that point. I guess you need to call this macro from [kernel/sched/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/core.c) file, which defines `CREATE_TRACE_POINTS` and includes `trace/events/sched.h`, where tracepoint `sched_switch` is declared.

Comment: You should use tracepoint_probe_register() with the tracepoint names of your interests. Here's an example: https://github.com/bytedance/Elkeid/blob/v1.9/driver/LKM/src/smith_hook.c#L5532